# Get http page after javascript has been loaded

Tags: javascript, html, c++, qt, parsing

I need to get HTML page when it is already with javascript results.
I use C++ and Qt

```
...
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MainWidget::onFinished);

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://website.com")));
...

void MainWidget::onFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << QString(reply->readAll());
}
```

but I only able to get such a thing:

```
<script>
        loadMap("mapContainer");                

    var baseStopId;

    function imReady() 
    {
      getMovie().addListener("MARKER_SHOW", "loadSurrounding");
...
</script>
```

and I need to get results.

Not a javascript but ready html page after proccessing javascript. Any advices? I have found something with Python, but I wish to know if there any C++ variants?

Comment: There's no way to know for certain that any web page has loaded completely; Javascript is a Turing complete language and is therefore subject to the halting problem.

Comment: Try adding `.html` to the end of the url?

Comment: .html is not the answer :D
"403 Forbidden"

Comment: @MrEricSir, and what about browsers? How do they actually get info about when to show loaded page? Or I misunderstand some basic things?

Comment: @Preonix js is executed from the client side, that is, the browser is responsible for executing it, but in your case it does not exist so it will not be possible. One possible option is to use QWebEnginePage.

Comment: As @eyllanesc commented , you can use a **hidden** `QWebEnginePage` and get the fully loaded page (**javascript executed**)

Comment: @eyllanesc thx as well as Redanium for help. I have already understood it and used some python modules to proccess js for me and then get full html page :D unfortunately I havent got WebEngine built into my Qt so to avoid using it I've researched into python libs, haha :D